# Should there be a new tag?

Tags: discussion

There is a tag "Anglican", defined as

> Referring to the Church of England or those churches in other countries that are in full Communion with it (e.g. The Episcopal Church in the US)

I would propose the addition of a new tag, "Continuing Anglican", to refer to those churches, and people (both clergy and laity), who claim to be Anglican, but which are not in full communion with the Church of England, such as "The Anglican Church of North America".

Comment: Can you point to any question(s) that could benefit from such a classification? We cannot create tags by themselves, they have to start their life being attached to something. I tend to think [@curiousdannii's suggestion](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6087/30) will be a better taxonomy but it would be nice to see some questions in context and decide based on that rather than just theoreticals.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be more appropriate to use the Anglican tag for all churches of an Anglican heritage, and introduce an Anglican-Communion tag for questions about only the churches in full communion with the CoE, if such questions arise.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 45 questions linked to the Anglicanism tag so I don't think there is much benefit to subdividing it, unless as Caleb says, there are examples where it would clearly help. I also think it would be rather confusing as the level of squabbling, or learned debate, amongst the primates is such that it is not always easy to follow who is in full communion with whom, and anyway it is somewhat fluid.

I do think the descriptor of the tag should be changed though. It currently says "Referring to the Church of England or those churches in other countries which are in full communion with it ...". I suggest it should be widened to include those who identify as Anglican but are not in full communion with the C of E (e.g. the ACNA);  but also narrowed to exclude those who are in full communion with the C of E but are not Anglican.

The Church of England is in full communion with:

- Most other Anglican churches.
- Most other national Protestant churches in Europe. These include the Church of Norway, Church of Sweden, Church of Denmark, the  Evangelical Lutheran Church of Finland, and others (but not the Church of Scotland).
- Some other Protestant churches such as the Lutheran Church in Great Britain and the Evangelical Lutheran Church in Lithuania.
- Some "Old Catholic" churches, most of which split from, or were excommunicated by, the Roman Catholic  Church over the issue of Papal infallibility following Vatican I. These
  exist in Germany, Austria, Switzerland, Holland, Poland, France and elsewhere.
- An Oriental church, the Mar Thoma Syrian Church, based principally  in the Indian state of Kerala, and said to have been founded by St Thomas in the first century.
- The Philippine Independent Church which split from Rome in 1902 over the role of Spanish Jesuits in the independence conflict.

This list includes Evangelical Lutheran, Old Catholic, Oriental and Independent churches, none of which would consider themselves, or be seen by others, as Anglican.

I would suggest "Referring to the Church of England and those churches in other countries which identify themselves as Anglican", although this seems a bit circular. The Catholicism tag mentions "the Catholic Church" which is equally circular and arguably more contentious if taken to apply only to the Roman Catholic Church.

Comment: Good point about non Anglican churches which are still in full communion. I don't think the tag needs to call out the CoE specifically, because there is (or there used to be) specific church-of-england and episcopal-church tags.

Comment: I agree - no need to mention C of E specifically

Comment: I edited the tag wiki :)